# Can you say: "What is and how to create art?"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm writing a blog post and I was wondering if a question could be formulated that way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Many speakers would indeed be troubled by that construction. You are linking or yoking two separate questions about art, in such a way that the word *art* itself occurs only once while figuring crucially in both questions. (Such yoking is termed *[zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis).)* Such economizing of verbiage can have a nice punchy effect—hence the temptation to do this. But the two questions, if we tease them apart, are not both equally suitable for asking either *directly* or *[indirectly](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/indirect_questions.htm).*

> What is art?

That’s a famously hard question to answer, but the question itself is unexceptionable in form, as long as it is a direct question. If we were to make it indirect, we would probably make one or two changes in it, inverting some word order and possibly shifting tense:

> He asked me what art was.

The other question, though, is already phrased so as to work better as an indirect question than as a direct one:

> *How to create art?

That form lacks a finite verb (the verb is infinitive, *to create),* and so it does not really work as a direct question, not even in informal conversational registers, though it could work as an indirect question:

> He asked me how to create art.

So since one of the two yoked questions is in a form only suitable for an indirect question, and the other is in a form more suitable for a direct question, they are ill yoked—like the ox and ass to which Odysseus, feigning insanity, hitched his plow.

Comment: A fine analysis.

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply said:

> What is art and how to create it?

Comment: Yes, I can do that but it still bugs me as to whether it's right.

Comment: I made a suggestion, not a guess.

Comment: Or using the structure of an indirect question : What art is and how to create it. (Compare: ''Plagiarism - What it is and how to avoid it')